# Ghost Localizable.strings used, "real" one ignored

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

Ok, this is getting on my nerves!

I must have done something wrong with a file but my app now uses captions from a "ghost" Localizable.strings. I have changed the content of the file since, but all the changes are ignored.

- I get the captions the "regular" way: `NSLocalizedString(@"captionKey", nil)`
- any change to the Localizable.strings is ignored
- if I delete the Localizable.strings reference **and file**, the app still displays proper captions!
- With the nslocalizable.strings deleted, I've searched for any file containing my captions and got nothing, yet when I build they are displayed.
- I've tried resetting the emulator, cleaning my project.. nothing. Still displaying old captions
- Same issue on my iPhone
- When I distribute the IPA over the air, this time, captions aren't displayed, just the keys

Please help!

**Edit:**
Following the comment from DarkDust I've deleted the app from iPhone, cleaned the project, built and run and the app now displays keys. Quite normal. But when I add a new Localizable.strings, it's being ignored. If it helps the code below logs `(null)`:

`NSLog(@"%@", [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] pathForResource:@"Localizable" ofType:@"strings"]);`

Comment: Did you delete the app from the phone, then cleaned your project and installed the app afresh?

Comment: Just done that. This time the app displays keys. Then I've added a new "Localizable.strings" with some content, cleaned again, deleted the app, built and the app still shows keys

Comment: It's finicky. I had this issue and then it resolved itself with no explanation a few days later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok found the issue.
I had somehow messed up with  the Build Rules (Xcode 4 -> select your target -> tab "Build Rules")
There, I had a few "CopyStringsFile" rules that were not using "CopyStringFile".
No idea how this happened.
All I had to do was removing them (making sure at least one was left using "CopyStringFile")

Tricky stuff